# How can add these items to a new dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I'm new at writing code and I'm having troubles with something about dictionaries and for loops.

```
    data = {}
    datain = {}
    
    for m in range(len(insdata)):
        
        if insdata[m][1] in [b for a in locdata for b in a]  and insdata[m][1] in [b for a in timedata for b in a] and insdata[m][1] in [b for a in timedata for b in a]:
            
            datain["Name"] = insdata[m][0]
            datain["Instructer"] = insdata[m][2]
            datain["Location"] = [x[1] for x in locdata for y in x if y == insdata[m][1]][0]
            datain["Days"] = [x[1] for x in timedata for y in x if y == insdata[m][1]][0]
            datain["Start Time"] = [x[2] for x in timedata for y in x if y == insdata[m][1]][0]
            datain["End Time"] = [x[3] for x in timedata for y in x if y == insdata[m][1]][0] 
            print(datain)
            
        else:
            pass
```

In the last part, I want to add that "datain" dictionary to my "data" dictionary. Briefly, I scanned some files and collected data from them, and I have no issues about that. When I printed "datain" inside the for loop, it's working properly; but, I want to take these outputs and collect them into one dictionary.
Here is the output of print function in my code:

```
{'Name': 'Introduction to Programming with Matlab', 'Instructer': 'Emre Kutukoglu', 'Location': 'SCI103', 'Days': 'TuTh', 'Start Time': '8:30', 'End Time': '9:45'}
{'Name': 'Programming with Python', 'Instructer': 'Ayca Tuzmen', 'Location': 'ENGZ50', 'Days': 'TuTh', 'Start Time': '13:00', 'End Time': '14:15'}
{'Name': 'Introduction to Programming', 'Instructer': 'Ayca Tuzmen', 'Location': 'SOSB16', 'Days': 'TuTh', 'Start Time': '16:00', 'End Time': '17:15'}
{'Name': 'Advanced Programming', 'Instructer': 'Attila Gursoy', 'Location': 'SNAA22', 'Days': 'TuTh', 'Start Time': '8:30', 'End Time': '9:45'}
{'Name': 'Introduction to Electrical and Electronics Engineering', 'Instructer': 'Ertugrul Basar', 'Location': 'SNAB172', 'Days': 'TuTh', 'Start Time': '14:30', 'End Time': '15:45'}
```

Let me explain it with my instructor's words.

PART A: Write a function called read_schedules() that reads course schedules from the 3
given files and stores them in a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
data = { “COMP110”: { “Name”: “Introduction to Programming with Matlab”,
“Instructor”: “Emre Kutukoglu”,
“Location”: “SCI103”,
“Days”: “TuTh”,
“Start Time”: “8:30”,
“End Time”: “9:45”},
“COMP125”: { “Name”: “Programming with Python”,
“Instructor”: “Ayca Tuzmen”,
“Location”: “ENGZ50”,
“Days”: “TuTh”,
“Start Time”: “13:00”,
“End Time”: “14:15”},
….
}
```

So, can you help me about that please ?

Comment: Oops, what a lot of code! I am sorry but I am too lazy to read it carefully to both understand what you are trying to do and where you failed. May be reading [ask]  could help you. Here my advice is that you should add debugging traces (simple `print` calls) throughout your code so that you can see *by yourself* where things start to go wrong. Then it will be possible to ask a more specific question with a [mcve] that others could use to reproduce the problem, which is often the first step for a fix. Good luck anyway...

Comment: Actually, the problem is about just the last for loop. I added the rest of the code because someone can want to see the rest to understand better. But you are right, I am shortening the code right now.

Comment: Do you have any information for how to get the key in the data dictionary? Because if that is included in the insdata you could just write in your for loop, after adding everything to datain: `data[KEY] = datain`

Comment: I will ask again, whether the Key for the data dictionary is random, or where you will get it from. The rest would be easy. If you found a solution yourself, it would also be great to post it for other people who encounter similiar problems